# Spring test/production application context

Tags: java, spring

Why when running spring tests with @ContextConfiguration(...) @Autowired works automatically and when running Java application I get NullPointerException?

With following example I get NullPointerException:

```
   public class FinalTest {

    @Autowired
    private App app;

    public FinalTest() {
    }

    public App getApp() {
        return app;
    }

    public void setApp(App app) {
        this.app = app;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

        FinalTest finalTest = new FinalTest();
        finalTest.getApp().getCar().print();
        finalTest.getApp().getCar().getWheel().print();
    }
}
```

With following example it works:

```
public class FinalTest {

    private App app;

    public FinalTest() {
    }

    public App getApp() {
        return app;
    }

    public void setApp(App app) {
        this.app = app;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

        FinalTest finalTest = new FinalTest();
        finalTest.setApp((App)context.getBean("app"));
        finalTest.getApp().getCar().print();
        finalTest.getApp().getCar().getWheel().print();
    }
}
```

In tests no need of doing context.getBean(), it just works with @Autowired:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/applicationContext-test.xml"})
public class AppTest{

    @Autowired
    private App app;

    @Test
    public void test(){

        assertEquals("This is a SEAT_test car.", this.app.getCar().toString());
        assertEquals("This is a 10_test wheel.", this.app.getCar().getWheel().toString());
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can do it with `@Autowired` in a non-test environment. Please give more context to what you are doing.

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do. Please show some more code in order for everyone to get a clear view of what you are trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anytime you use `@Autowired`, the class into which the dependency is going to be injected needs to be managed by Spring.

A test with:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/applicationContext-test.xml"})
```

is managed by Spring. When the annotations do not exist, the class is not managed by Spring and therefor no
 dependency injection is performed

Comment: Ok, now I understand the point with the tests managed by Spring. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You're expecting Spring to be able to inject beans into an instance it doesn't manage.

You're creating your object manually

```
FinalTest finalTest = new FinalTest();
```

Spring can only inject beans into objects it manages. Here, Spring has nothing to do with the object created above.

Declare a `FinalTest` bean in your context and retrieve it. It will have been autowired if your configuration is correct.

Comment: Ok, I understand that, but why in tests that is possible? Is it because a test is an object managed by Spring?

Comment: @David This has nothing to do with tests. It has to do with your configuration. In your test, Spring creates a bean for your test class. Since it manages that bean, it can autowire the `App` bean. It would be able to do the same if you declared a bean of type `FinalTest`.